# cuda SM register limit

Tags: cuda

I know number of block running on one SM is limited by block number, threads, shared memory, and register. Is there any strategy to avoiding having too many registers? I mean I just don't want to have too many of them, eventually it limits the number of block I run on one SM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the main drivers for the number of registers is amount of local data you declare in your kernel. However, the PTX assembler can do quite a good job of re-using registers, so it's not always easy to work out how many will be used from the PTX code - you need to run `ptxas` to get the real answer.

Answer (score 9):

Compiling with `nvcc -Xptxas -v` will print out the diagnostic information Edric mentioned.  Additionally, you can force the compiler to conserve registers using the `__launch_bounds__` qualifier.  For example

```
__global__ void
__launch_bounds__(maxThreadsPerBlock, minBlocksPerMultiprocessor)
MyKernel(...)
{ 
   ...
}
```

guarantees that at least `minBlocksPerMultiprocessor` blocks of size `maxThreadsPerBlock` will fit on a single SM. See Section B.16 of the [CUDA Programming Guide](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/3_1/toolkit/docs/NVIDIA_CUDA_C_ProgrammingGuide_3.1.pdf) for a complete explanation of `__launch_bounds__`.